# asp.net gridview template field with second row spanning mutiple columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, aspxgridview

Good Afternoon,
I would like to know if this is possible. I have a gridview with several (4 template fields).  The 4 fields include

1. First Name
2. Last Name
3. Phone
4. Email

What I would like to do is get a fifth data column(address) completely on a different row so that the data looks like this.

- Row #1 | First Name | Last Name | Phone | Email|     Record #1
- Row #2 | Address                               |     Record #1
- Row #3 | First Name | Last Name | Phone | Email|     Record #2
- Row #4 | Address                               |     Record #2

Can anybody help me with this, please?

Comment: Use repeater instead of grid view for this logic !

Comment: Does the repeater control allow edits/deletes on the row? Apologies for this question if it sounds simplistic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason this question is upvoted. I will wrote you an answer:

```
<table>
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repeater1" >
       <ItemTemplate>
          <tr>
               <td> <%#Eval("FirstName")%></td>
               <td> <%#Eval("LastName")%></td>
                    ....//other <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
               <td><%#Eval("Address")%></td>
          </tr>
       </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</table>
```

I will leave for you the css part, also if you want to have column names look into `<th>` tags, but I don't know how you will achieve that properly when you have on row 1 columns different form row 2. If you want to have delete/edit functionality you should add new `td` with `linkButton/ImageButton/Button` with functionality which will delete/edit the current row. For this you will need `<%#Eval("ID")%>` in `CommandArguments` of the button. But again in this case this will be interesting because you have one record on 2 rows. The design decision is done by you this is the solution.

You should probably look how to have multiple columns on row 1 and only one on row 2, this was attribute of td [colspan](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp)

In code behind:

```
        repeater1.DataSource = dst; // this should be data set containing all the needed values
        repeater1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it isn't more common knowledge that you can do this in a GridView. You can mix and match spanned rows and throw some regular GridView columns on at the end of the span (bound or templated).

You do lose some of the bells and whistles of the GridView, because you will have to manually handle sorting and some of the other things that make the GridView easy to work with. But unlike the Repeater, you still get some of the extra functionality of the GridView.

If you throw together a datasource that matches the fields I'm binding to here, you will see it has a second row that spans multiple columns (all the way to the last templated column of the GridView).

It's basically a header template, Two HTML tables, and then whatever type of GridView columns you need after that, if any at all.

The first html table is the normal row. The second html table is the just a long row to put something like a long description or notes.

Didn't include the CSS here, but that's how you will format column widths and alignment.

Works fine, but it sure takes longer to build these. You have to spend a lot of time adjusting column widths, and it is a pain to get the header column to match up with row columns. But, not much different than what you would run into making a template for a repeater.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" AutoGenerateColumns="False" runat="server" >
      
      <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                        <table id="Table1" runat="server" >   
                    <tr id="Tr1" runat="server" >   
                    <td id="Td1" style="width: 55px; text-align: center; vertical-align: bottom; border-right: solid 1px black;" runat="server">
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbPoNoSort" CommandArgument="id" CommandName="Sort" runat="server">ID#</asp:LinkButton></td>   
                    <td id="Td2" style="width: 85px;" runat="server"> 
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbDateRequested" CommandArgument="ReqDate" CommandName="Sort" runat="server">Date</asp:LinkButton></td>   
                    <td id="Td3" style="width: 100px; text-align: center; vertical-align: bottom; border-left: solid 1px black; border-right: solid 1px black;" runat="server">
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lblNameSort" CommandArgument="col2" CommandName="Sort" runat="server">Name</asp:LinkButton></td>   
                    <td id="Td4" style="width: 130px; text-align: center; vertical-align: bottom; border-left: solid 1px black; border-right: solid 1px black;" runat="server">
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lblApprovSort" CommandArgument="approved_by" CommandName="Sort" runat="server">User</asp:LinkButton></td>   
                    <td id="Td5" style="width: 175px; text-align: center; vertical-align: bottom; border-left: solid 1px black; border-right: solid 1px black;" runat="server">
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbVendorSort" CommandArgument="vendor" CommandName="Sort" runat="server">Vendor</asp:LinkButton></td>  
                    <td id="Td7" style="width: 150px; text-align: center; vertical-align: bottom; border-left: solid 1px black; border-right: solid 1px black;" runat="server"> 
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbTypeSort" CommandArgument="col4" CommandName="Sort" runat="server">Type</asp:LinkButton></td>  
                    <td id="Td8" style="width: 65px; text-align: center; vertical-align: bottom; border-left: solid 1px black; border-right: solid 1px black;" runat="server">
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbNoSort" CommandArgument="col5" CommandName="Sort" runat="server">OrderNo</asp:LinkButton></td>  
                    <td id="Td9" style="width: 90px; text-align: center; vertical-align: bottom; border-left: solid 1px black; border-right: solid 1px black;" runat="server">
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbCostSort" CommandArgument="col6" CommandName="Sort" runat="server">Est. Cost</asp:LinkButton></td>  
                    <td id="Td10" style="width: 75px; text-align: center; vertical-align: bottom; border-left: solid 1px black; border-right: solid 1px black;" runat="server">
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbPaymentTypeSort" CommandArgument="col10" CommandName="Sort" runat="server">Payment Type</asp:LinkButton></td>
                    <td id="Td11" style="width: 75px; text-align: center; vertical-align: bottom; border-left: solid 1px black; border-right: solid 1px black;" runat="server">
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbLocationSort" CommandArgument="col7" CommandName="Sort" runat="server">Inventory Location</asp:LinkButton></td>
                    <td id="Td12" style="width: 75px; text-align: center; vertical-align: bottom; border-left: solid 1px black;" runat="server">
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbDeliverySort" CommandArgument="col13" CommandName="Sort" runat="server">Delivery Method</asp:LinkButton></td>
                    </tr> 
                </table>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>

              
        <table >
            <tr>   
                <td style="width: 55px; text-align: center; vertical-align: top; border-right: solid 1px black;">   
                    <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%# Bind("id") %>'></asp:Label>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbPoNo" CommandName="View" runat="server" Visible="true" Text='<%# Bind("id") %>' ></asp:LinkButton>
                </td>   
                <td style="width: 85px; text-align: center; vertical-align: top; border-left: solid 1px black; border-right: solid 1px black;">   
                    <asp:Label  ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Date")%>' >   
                    </asp:Label>   
                </td>  
                <td style="width: 100px; text-align: center; vertical-align: top; border-left: solid 1px black; border-right: solid 1px black;">    
                    <asp:Label  ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("col1")%>' >   
                    </asp:Label>   
                </td>  
                <td style="width: 130px; text-align: center; vertical-align: top; border-left: solid 1px black; border-right: solid 1px black;">   
                    <asp:Label  ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("col2")%>' >   
                    </asp:Label>   
                </td>  
                <td style="width: 175px; text-align: center; vertical-align: top; border-left: solid 1px black; border-right: solid 1px black;">   
                    <asp:Label  ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("col3")%>' >   
                    </asp:Label>  
                </td>   
                 <td style="width: 150px; text-align: center; vertical-align: top; border-left: solid 1px black; border-right: solid 1px black;">   
                    <asp:Label  ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("col4")%>' >   
                    </asp:Label>  
                </td>   
                 <td style="width: 65px; text-align: center; vertical-align: top; border-left: solid 1px black; border-right: solid 1px black;">   
                   <asp:LinkButton ID="lbOrderNo" runat="server" CommandName="ViewOrder" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "col5") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
                </td>  
                <td style="width: 90px; text-align: center; vertical-align: top; border-left: solid 1px black; border-right: solid 1px black;" runat="server">   
                    <asp:Label  ID="Label8" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("col6")%>' >   
                    </asp:Label>  
                </td>  
                <td style="width: 75px; text-align: center; vertical-align: top; border-left: solid 1px black; border-right: solid 1px black;" runat="server">   
                    <asp:Label  ID="Label9" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("col7")%>' >   
                    </asp:Label>  
                </td>  
                <td style="width: 75px; text-align: center; vertical-align: top; border-left: solid 1px black; border-right: solid 1px black;">   
                    <asp:Label  ID="Label10" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("col8")%>' >   
                    </asp:Label>  
                </td>  
                <td style="width: 75px; text-align: center; vertical-align: top; border-left: solid 1px black;">   
                    <asp:Label  ID="Label11" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("col9")%>' >   
                    </asp:Label>  
                </td>                     
            </tr>
           </table>
                <table class="job-info">
                    <tr class="TableData">   
                <td style="width: 1100px">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label13" CssClass="details" runat="server" Text="Details:" ></asp:Label> <asp:Label  ID="Label12" BackColor="WhiteSmoke" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("col10")%>' >   
                    </asp:Label>  
                </td>
            </tr>
           </table>              

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>                
      <asp:TemplateField Visible="True" HeaderText="Accounting">
    <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:CheckBox ID="check"  runat="server" Enabled="False" />
     </ItemTemplate>
     <HeaderStyle Width="60px" />
     <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
      </asp:TemplateField>
            
    </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```